# How should I deal with the problem about generics with the nullable option from C# 8.0?

Tags: c#

Recently I have a trouble between if a generic type is a class or a struct, in detail, when I declare `T` to have neither constraint of `class` nor `struct` and also the `#nullable` option is enabled then the generic type gets some unexpected behaviors. For example, if I construct a member with the type `T?` and `T` is specified to a non-nullable struct type, the `T?` type does not operate as a nullable struct. Here's an explanation code about it:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    ...
    public MyClass (T value, T? another) { ... }

    public void DoExample () {
        MyClass<int> a = new MyClass<int>(1, null); /* causes the CS1503 error, indicating int cannot receive null.
        In other words, T? is still int, not the nullable int.*/
    }
}
```

What and how should I do to settle this problem?

---

**Maybe Solved**

Finally I've found an incomplete but well-reasonable solution to resolve it. The following  would help us approach the problem.

```
public class NullableWrapper<T> where T : notnull /* this constraint is not necessary
but if you want every type that specifies T to be non-nullable
and/or would not like to consider the null reference exception which may arise at Equals,
GetHashCode, and ToString, that would modify the type accuracy and/or your need. */ {
    public T Value { get; set; } = default!;

    internal NullableWrapper (T value) => this.Value = value;

    public override bool Equals (object? obj) => this.Value.Equals(obj);
    public override int GetHashCode () => this.Value.GetHashCode();
    public override string? ToString () => $"NullableWrapper({this.Value})";

    public static implicit operator NullableWrapper<T> (T itself)
        => new NullableWrapper<T>(itself);
    public static implicit operator T (NullableWrapper<T> itself)
        => itself.Value;
}
```

Then, my prior code is altered to what appears below:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : notnull {
    ...
    public MyClass (T value, NullableWrapper<T>? another) { ... }

    public void DoExample () {
        MyClass<int> a = new MyClass<int>(1, null); // this causes none of error.
        MyClass<string> b = new MyClass<string>("hello", null); // similarly, no error happens.
        MyClass<double> c = new MyClass<double>(2.6, 5.2); // it's equivalent to the previous.
        MyClass<string> d = new MyClass<string>("asd", "def"); // as well.
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this work
 MyClass<int> a = new MyClass<int>(1, (int?)null)

Comment: Under the covers, nullable reference types are completely different to nullable value types, which means you can't have generic, nullable either value or reference type.

Comment: Read about it: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-11-25.md

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Nullable reference types exist only at compile time: `Foo<string>` and `Foo<string?>` are compiled to the same `Foo<System.String>`.
- Nullable value types are different: `int` is `System.Int32`, `int?` is `System.Nullable<System.Int32>`.

When you have `class MyClass<T>` **without** `where T : struct`, the compiler defaults to the nullable reference type behavior, where `int?` does not really make sense, but is still treated as `Int32`, and not `Nullable<Int32>` like you expect, and `null` is not a valid value for `Int32`.

It is not possible to have a generic type like this as of .NET 5 / C# 9. It works for either `class` or for `struct`, but not both.

@insane_developer provided a link to the LDM meeting where this was discussed:
https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-11-25.md#problem-1-t-and-t-mean-different-things

> #### Problem 1: T? and T? mean different things
>
> The first problem is not technical, but one of perception and language regularity. Consider:
>
> ```cs
> public T? M1<T>(T t) where T : struct;
> public T? M2<T>(T t);
>
> var i1 = M1(7); // i1 is int?
> var i2 = M2(7); // i2 is int
> ```
>
> The declaration of `M1` is legal today. Because `T` is constrained to a (nonnullable) value type, `T?` is known to be a nullable value type, and hence, when instantiated with `int`, the return type is `int?`.
>
> The declaration of `M2` is what's proposed to allow. Because `T` is unconstrained, `T?` is "the type of `default(T)`". When instantiated with `int` the type of `default(int)` is `int`, so that is the return type.
>
> In other words, for the same provided `T` these two methods have *different* return types, even though the only difference is that one has a constraint on `T` but the other does not.
>
> The cognitive dissonance here was a major part of why we didn't embrace `T?` for unconstrained `T`.

Comment: So, according to your answer and contents of the link you attached, it seems that those do not exist currently any ways to solve this problem with the native support by C#. I see, and I hope C# would take in the future some grammars to deal with the problem and satisfy the need about it.